# Recalculate the value of a variable as soon as one of the elements required to calculate it changes

Tags: genexus

I have the following problem:

I have a webpanel 'Reservations' on which the user specifies the values for a `&beginDate` and an `&endDate` (Edit).The variables `&beginDate` and `&endDate` are used as conditions for a grid.

I also have a `&days` variable (readonly), which is defined in rules as the difference between those two `(&days=&endDate-beginDate)`, and its purpose is twofold:

1. To calculate the rate of the Reservation - this works just fine
2. To be displayed for the user. - this doesn't work as fine

My issue is that if the user updates the value of either `&endDate` or `&beginDate` the `&days` value isn't updated until after the grid is loaded or refreshed. I need it to change as soon as either of those.

I tried the following before looking for help:

1. Setting `notifycontextchange=true` for `&beginDate` and `&endDate` and creating two TrackContext events:

`

```
Event TrackContext(&beginDate)
&days=&endDate-&beginDate
endevent

Event TrackContext(&endDate)
&days=&endDate-&beginDate
endevent
```

2. Assign its value in start event
3. Assign its value on a `&beginDate.click` and an `&endDate.click` Event

I already scanned these forums and found an answer that suggested using a ControlValueChanged event. The problem is that I am running Genexus X Ev1 and that event doesnt exist in here (or at least is not inherently tied to the variable).

Is there any other solution? I feel like I'm missing something truly simple :(

Im working with HTML 4.01 Transitional and a .NET environment.

Comment: Can we see some code please ? The prose description is hard for me to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Genexus X EV1 upg 3 onwards you can have events that run in the browser (don't need to refresh the grid) [SAC 30737](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,S,0,,30737).

Try adding IsValid Events:

```
Event &beginDate.IsValid
    &days = &endDate - beginDate
EndEvent
Event &endDate.IsValid
    &days = &endDate - beginDate
EndEvent
```